# Dimension of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand this example:

> Let $f(T_1,T_2)\subset k[T_1,T_2]$ be a non-constant irreducible polynomial. Let
>   $X=Z(f)\subset \mathbb A^2$. We will see that $\dim(X)=1$. We have
>   $k[X]=k[T_1,T_2]/(f)$ and
>
> $$\dim(X)= \operatorname{tr.deg}_k k(X) \lneq \operatorname{tr.deg}_k k(T_1,T_2) = 2.$$
>
> Since in $k(X)$ the generators $T_1, T_2$ follow to an algebraic
>   relation $f$. On the other hand, $\dim(X)\ge 1$ since $X$ is not finite, thus $\dim (X)=1.$

I didn't understand why the $\lt$ part and why $\operatorname{tr.deg}_k(k(T_1,T_2))=2$. Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why downvoted??

Comment: You've been asking quite a few questions lately and in every instance it turns out you struggle with the concept of transcendence degree. This, I guess, caused the downvotes on this question, because you're essentially again asking "what is transcendence degree?"

Comment: @Magdiragdag sorry, but I'm not asking that.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I totally disagree with the downvotes, I know the rules of the site and I follow the meta site daily and I'm sure my questions meet the quality standards of the MSE.

Answer (score 2):

$T_1$ and $T_2$ satisfy an algebraic relation in $k[X] = k[T_1,T_2]/(f)$, but not in $k(T_1,T_2)$.  The latter notation is specifically chosen to refer to the field in which $T_1$ and $T_2$ are formal variables with no relations, and the transcendence degree of such a field over $k$ equals $2$ by pretty much any definition of transcendence degree.

Comment: I guess I didn't really say why the transcendence degree of $k(X)$ is strictly less than $2$.  For a fact like this, I recommend trying to write down the abstract, general statement that would imply the specific case.  Here, we have a field, $k(X)$, generated by two elements, $T_1$ and $T_2$, with a relation between them: $f(T_1,T_2) = 0$.  This alone should be enough to tell you that the transcendence degree is strictly less than 2—and it is!  Otherwise, we can decompose $k(X) / k$ into two simple extensions, by $T_1$ and $T_2$, both with transcendence degree 1, implying no relations.